# Django authentication error : 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am having problem in Django authentication, whenever I try to login it gives 'str' object has no attribute 'pk' error.
I am using MySql as my database.

```py
# views.py
def user_login(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
     form = AuthenticationForm(request,data=request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
         password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
         user = authenticate( username= username,password= password)
         if user is not None:
             login(request,username)
             return redirect('app:home')
         else:
             return render(request,'404error.html',context={})
     else:
         return render(request,'404error.html',context={})

 form = AuthenticationForm()
 return render(request,'login.html',context={'form':form})

def user_logout(request):
 logout(request)
 return redirect('app:home')
```

```py
#urls.py
# from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
# from app import urls
from . import views
app_name = 'app'

urlpatterns = [

    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/',views.user_login,name='user_login'),

]
```

Comment: can you show full error tracback

Comment: File "C:\Users\hrshk\Desktop\mysite2\app\views.py" in user_login
  33.     login(request,username)

Comment: See the below answer it will solve it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [**`login(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) a `User` object, so `user`, not the <s>`username`</s>, so:

```
    …
    login(request, user)
    …
```